# Angular 2 : Can't access files in assets folder

Tags: html, angular

I am having an error 404, when I tried to access local file within my app.
I can't access and display a pdf that I put in a sub-folder (pdf) within assets folder.I am using cli

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="./assets/pdf/fef.pdf"/>
```

the error it display "GET http://localhost:4200/app/assets/pdf/fef.pdf 404 (Not Found)"

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Not sure but I don't think the `app` folder should be a part of your path

Comment: Actually it is not, I was just trying to figure out if this could work. I corrected and update it to the current state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to template bind the `src` change it to:

```html
<embed width="100%" height="100%" [src]="'assets/pdf/fef.pdf'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure that worked, it had nothing to do with the template binding.

```
src="assets/pdf/fef.pdf"
```

Would have worked as well. Your reference wasn't working because you were using a relative path, `./` in place of an absolute one. So your app was looking for the image in `app/assets` because you were relative to the app folder. Angular paths take some getting used to.

An absolute path starts you relative to the `src` folder.

I believe a relative path starts you in the `app` folder, regardless of the component template it is called from. I will have to verify that though.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem for images, it was that my absolute path contains special characters like "(", ")" and spaces, moving my project folder to C:/ fixes the problem, now I can add the image using `src="assets/img.png"`